# Match arms have incompatible types. Expected struc `NaiveDate`, found `()`

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'm new to Rust and am trying to wrap my head around error handling.

I'm trying to return error if parsing the date goes wrong, here is the function:

```rust
pub fn create_posts(contents: &Vec<String>) -> Result<Vec<Post>, CreatePostError> {
    const TITLE_SEP: &str = "Title: ";
    const DESC_SEP: &str = "Description: ";
    const DATE_SEP: &str = "Date: ";
    const TAGS_SEP: &str = "Tags: ";

    let mut posts: Vec<Post> = Vec::new();
    for entry in contents {
        let lines = entry.lines().collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let metadata = lines[0].contains(&TITLE_SEP)
            && lines[1].contains(&DESC_SEP)
            && lines[2].contains(&DATE_SEP)
            && lines[3].contains(&TAGS_SEP);

        if metadata {
            let date = &lines[2][DATE_SEP.len()..];
            let parsed_date = match NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date, "%Y-%m-%d") {
                Ok(parsed_date) => parsed_date,
                Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {:?}", CreatePostError::ParseError { inner_err: e }),
            };

            let tags: Vec<String> = lines[3][TAGS_SEP.len()..]
                .split(", ")
                .map(|s| s.to_string())
                .collect();
            let mut article_content = String::new();
            for line in &lines[4..] {
                article_content.push_str(line);
                article_content.push_str("\n")
            }
            let post = Post {
                title: lines[0][TITLE_SEP.len()..].to_string(),
                description: lines[1][DESC_SEP.len()..].to_string(),
                date: parsed_date,
                tags,
                content: article_content,
            };
            posts.push(post);
        } else {
            return Err(CreatePostError::MetadataError);
        }
    }

    return Ok(posts);
}
```

You can see the full code here since i wrote custom errors: [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0bbe8a7b2089811dc6c2d422758a0463)

The problem I'm having is with this part:

```
let date = &lines[2][DATE_SEP.len()..];
let parsed_date = match NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date, "%Y-%m-%d") {
    Ok(parsed_date) => parsed_date,
    Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {:?}", CreatePostError::ParseError { inner_err: e }),
};
```

I'm getting `match arms have incompatible types. Expected struct NaiveDate, found ()`

Here is my `enum` and `impl` for the error:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum CreatePostError {
    ReadFileError { path: PathBuf },
    MetadataError,
    ParseError { inner_err: ParseError },
}

impl fmt::Display for CreatePostError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::ReadFileError { path } => write!(f, "Error reading file {path:?}"),
            Self::MetadataError => write!(f, "Some metadata is missing"),
            Self::ParseError { inner_err } => {
                write!(f, "Error parsing date: {inner_err}")
            }
        }
    }
}

impl From<chrono::format::ParseError> for CreatePostError {
    fn from(e: chrono::format::ParseError) -> Self {
        CreatePostError::ParseError { inner_err: e }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, `eprintln!` does indeed return `()`, so... did you mean to return an error from that arm?

Comment: Yes. If i return just the error `CreatePostError::ParseError { inner_err: e}` it still gives me incompatible types. It says `expect struct NaiveDate, found CreatePostError`.

Comment: You need to return a `Result`, which means you need to wrap returned errors in `Err`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have a result here, here is a way to do it:

```
let parsed_date = match NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date, "%Y-%m-%d") {
            Ok(parsed_date) => Ok(parsed_date),
            Err(e) => {eprintln!("Error: {:?}", &e);
                       Err(CreatePostError::ParseError { inner_err: e }}),
}?;
```

The `?` is saying: if the thing before is an error, return it, and if it is Ok, unwrap it.

This pattern is so common that rust's result gives a lot of utilities to make this kind of things easier. Here, the `map_err` function would make it more straightforward: [map_err](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err)

see:

```
let parsed_date = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                 .map_err(|e| {
                      eprintln!("Error: {:?}", &e);
                      CreatePostError::ParseError { inner_err: e }})?;
```

But it is only a matter of preference and it might be a lot to digest if you are just beginning, so you can choose the way that you like the most.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there is a lot to learn right now. I come from Go and the error handling there is simpler and not this powerful.